# How to know if my kernel of ubuntu is supporting conntrack

Tags: kernel, iptables

I want to know if there is a way to know if the `conntrack` module are loaded in my Linux kernel.

How to know if my kernel of Ubuntu is supporting `conntrack`?

Comment: Why do you think it is not loaded?

Comment: @Pilot6 I want to check on my client server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the kernel configuration file, specifically the value of parameter `CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK`.

On my system, the NF (NetFilter) subsystem comes with `conntrack` module, here:

```
% grep '^CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK=' /boot/config-"$(uname -r)"
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK=m
```

Check the output in your case, if you see `m` as the value of the parameter then `conntrack` comes as a loadable module, whereas `y` indicates it is built into the kernel, and `n` indicates absense.

Answer (score 4):

To find out if the conntrack module is loaded into the kernel open a terminal and type `lsmod | grep <module name>` if the module is loaded then it should show up if not then it is not loaded. unfortunately i do not know how to check if a particular module is compatible with a particular kernel other than trying to run the module and see what happens.